# JavaScript reduce returns object on Array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have an array of objects, let's say `[{x:2, y:3}, {x:5, y:4}]` and i call `reduce((c, n) => c.y + n.y);` on it. It obviouslly returns `7`.

However, if the array contains a single object, let's say `[{x:2, y:4}]` the same reduce call will return the object itself `{x:2, y:4}`.

Is this normal behaviour? Am I obliged to check if the result is an object and not an number afterwards?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, this is the normal behaviour of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) when you don't pass an initial value for the accumulator (which you *always* should). Your code doesn't work as expected on any arrays other than those with two objects.

Go for

```
arr.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el.y, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, just saw it in the MDN docs, I overlooked when checking. They provide a "foolproof" solution using `map()`, however it will affect performance, won't it ?

Comment: There's hardly any noticeable difference, use what you think is easier to understand. You don't need `map`, you can always integrate the mapping in your reducer function.

Answer (score 5):

It is intended behaviour, when you don't provide an initial value (second argument to `reduce`). From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

> If the array is empty and no `initialValue` was provided, `TypeError` would be thrown. If the array has only one element (regardless of position) and no `initialValue` was provided, or if `initialValue` is provided but the array is empty, the solo value would be returned *without calling* `callback`.

It comes with the following advise:

> It is usually safer to provide an initial value because there are three possible outputs without `initialValue`.

So write:

```
reduce((c, n) => c.y + n.y, { y: 0 });
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because reduce function can take 1 more argument - default value and if its not specified it takes firs value of array. That's why it works for more than one.

However if you do it like this

```js
let a = [{x:5, y:4}].reduce((c, n) => c + n.y, 0);

console.log(a)
```

it sums propertly.

Answer (score 3):

Did you initialize the accumulator to `{ y : 0}`

If you did not then it will return the original object.

```
let sum = data.reduce((c, n) => {
  return { "y" : c.y + n.y };
}, { y : 0 });
```

Comment: @Bergi You are right. Fixed it. Now the accumulator will always be an object with `y` key.

Answer (score 2):

Note: If initialValue isn't provided, reduce will execute the callback function starting at index 1, skipping the first index. If initialValue is provided, it will start at index 0.

If the array is empty and no initialValue is provided, TypeError will be thrown. If the array has only one element (regardless of position) and no initialValue is provided, or if initialValue is provided but the array is empty, the solo value will be returned without calling callback.

It is usually safer to provide an initial value because there are three possible outputs without initialValue, as shown in the following example.