# Sum values of collection by type and assign to new property on replicated object

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm trying to sum values from a collection and add them to a new property for each object

```
var collection = [
 {prop:'title',quan:2},
 {prop:'body',quan:3},
 {prop:'title',quan:2},
 {prop:'title',quan:4},
]

/* desired result
 [
  {prop:'title', quan:2, stock:8},
  {prop:'body', quan:3, stock:3},
  {prop:'title', quan:2, stock:8},
  {prop:'title', quan:4, stock:8},
 ]
*/
```

I've tried many different ways with no success. I am trying to do this in a functional way.

This were I am currently stuck and I'm quite sure it is the most concise way.

```
// group the props using key
var result = _.groupBy(collection,'prop');
```

which outputs

```
{
  title:[
   {prop:'title',quan:2},{prop:'title',quan:2},{prop:'title',quan:4}
  ], 
  body:[
   {prop:'body':quan:3}
  ]
}
```

So let's reduce the arrays we've created

```
var obj = {};
_.forEach(result,function(value,key){    
    obj[key] = _.reduce(value,function(acc,val){
      return acc.quan + val.quan
    });       
});
```

This section above isn't working though?

When I have that working, I should be able to map it back to my final collection.

we know totals, map them to collection

```
var final = _.map(collection,function(value){
  return {
    type:value.prop,
    val:value.quan,
    stock:obj[value.prop]
  }
});
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qokilif/edit?js,output)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript reduce returns object on Array of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42378202/1048572)

Comment: *"I am trying to do this in a functional way."* – then you shouldn't be mutating your input, fwiw

Comment: @noamik I've done some reading since you mentioned data should not be mutated and have a better understanding of functional programming now, although your answer is still a little beyond my comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to get the sum object and then assign the sum to the corresponding object. Like this:

```js
function stock(arr) {
  // using lodach: var sum = _.reduce(arr, ...)
  var sum = arr.reduce(function(s, o) {     // get the sum object (hashing)
    s[o.prop] = (s[o.prop] || 0) + o.quan;  // if the sum already contains an entry for this object porp then add it to its quan otherwise add 0
    return s;
  }, {});
  
  // using lodash: _.forEach(arr, ...);
  arr.forEach(function(o) {                 // assign the sum to the objects
    o.stock = sum[o.prop];                  // the stock for this object is the hash of it's prop from the sum object
  });
}

var collection = [
 {prop:'title',quan:2},
 {prop:'body',quan:3},
 {prop:'title',quan:2},
 {prop:'title',quan:4},
]

stock(collection);
console.log(collection);
```

If you want to return a new array and leave the original intact, use `map` like you already did instead of `forEach` like this:

```
// using lodash: _.map(arr, ...);
return arr.map(function(o) {                // create new objects with stock property
  return {
    prop: o.prop,
    quan: o.quan,
    stock: sum[o.prop]
  };
  // or in ecmascript: return Object.assign({}, o, {stock: sum[o.prop]});
});
```

And then you'll have to use it like this:

```
var newArray = stock(collection);
```

Comment: I was close to that sometime ago, but veered wildly off, thanks.

Comment: Nice answer! I cant think of any simpler way to do it

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir ah i see that now. sorry about that. i'll delete my previous comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I like this solution better because it abstracts away the collation but allows you to control how items are collated using a higher-order function.

Notice how we don't talk about the kind or structure of data at all in the collateBy function – this keeps our function generic and allows for it to work on data of any shape.

`collateBy` takes a grouping function `f` and a reducing function `g` and a homogenous array of any type of data

```js
// collateBy :: (a -> b) -> ((c,a) -> c) -> [a] -> Map(b:c)
const collateBy = f => g => xs => {
  return xs.reduce((m,x) => {
    let v = f(x)
    return m.set(v, g(m.get(v), x))
  }, new Map())
}

const collateByProp = collateBy (x => x.prop)

const assignTotalStock = xs => {
  let stocks = collateByProp ((acc=0, {quan}) => acc + quan) (xs)
  return xs.map(({prop, quan}) =>
    ({prop, quan, stock: stocks.get(prop)}))
}

var collection = [
 {prop:'title',quan:2},
 {prop:'body',quan:3},
 {prop:'title',quan:2},
 {prop:'title',quan:4},
]

console.log(assignTotalStock(collection))
// [ { prop: 'title', quan: 2, stock: 8 },
//   { prop: 'body', quan: 3, stock: 3 },
//   { prop: 'title', quan: 2, stock: 8 },
//   { prop: 'title', quan: 4, stock: 8 } ]
```

Performing collations is very common when manipulating data, so it doesn't make sense to encode collation behaviour in each function that needs it. Instead, use a generic, higher-order function that captures only the essence of a collation computation, and specialize it using grouping function `f` and reducing function `g`